# HTML Form onSubmit event with JS ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to test and then implement the onSubmit event for a form that I have placed in my HTML page. When the submit button is clicked, an alert should pop up as defined in the corresponding JavaScript function. However, nothing happens upon clicking and my browser's web console shows "**ReferenceError**: onSubmitQA is not defined" as output.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz Game</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Corben:bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nobile" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/subpage_styles.css">
    <script src="../js/script_quiz.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "text">
    <a id="logo" href="../index.html"><img src = "../images/web_logo.png"></a>
    <h1>(Quiz Header)</h1>

    <h3>Question 1:</h3>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vabnZ9-ex7o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h4>Is the song in the video above:</h4>
    <form onsubmit="onSubmitQA(event.target)">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1_1" name="alternative" value = "pop">Pop<br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1_2" name="alternative" value = "altenative">Rock<br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1_3" name="alternative" value = "alternative">Alternative<br>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1_4" name="alternative" value = "hiphop">Hip Hop<br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

The contents of the linked JS file:

```
function onSubmitQA(e) {
    alert("Submitted");
}
```

I thought the issue could have been a typo in the JS file's path, but even when the JS file is placed in the same directory as the HTML file, the error still occurs. Some help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to add the function to the window object like so:

```
<script>
    window.onSubmitQA = onSubmitQA
</script>
```

What you should probably do though is:

```
<form id="myForm" ...

<script>
    document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", onSubmitQA)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Your index.html file can't simply find your script. Can You provide your folder structure? Because if You set your  like this - "../" - it means your index.html is placed in the folder, so structure should be something like this ->

- js/script_quiz.js
- css/subpage_styles.css
- images/
- public/index.html

So simply check path from html to your script file.

Comment: I already tested with the JS file in the same directory as HTML, with <script src="script_quiz.js"></script>, and the error still occurs.